# how to solve incompatible types of a constructor

Tags: java, android, proguard

I created a jar file the contains a class named DEM. DEM class has one constructor and it accepts String parameter. when I imported that jar file into Android App and initialize the constructor whith a string parameter, i receive
the following error

```
Error:(563, 75) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
```

and I do not have any boolean constructor. how to solve this problem?

**constructor**:

```
public DEM(String fms1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
            this.mInputHistoryArray[i][j] = Double.NaN;
        }
    }
    this.inputHistory(this.mInputHistoryArray);

    String[] splittedFMS1 = fms1.split(",");
    this.mInputUpdateArray[0] = TimeUtils.getTSSec() - this.mStartTime;
    this.mInputUpdateArray[1] = Double.valueOf(splittedFMS1[4]);
    this.mInputUpdateArray[2] = Double.valueOf(splittedFMS1[7]);
    this.mInputUpdateArray[3] = Double.valueOf(splittedFMS1[3]);
    this.mInputUpdateArray[4] = Double.valueOf(splittedFMS1[5]);
    this.mInputUpdateArray[5] = Double.NaN;
    this.mInputUpdateArray[6] = Double.NaN;
    this.mInputUpdateArray[7] = Double.valueOf(splittedFMS1[8]);
    this.mInputUpdateArray[8] = Double.valueOf(splittedFMS1[9]);
    this.inputUpdate(this.mInputUpdateArray);

    this.mOutputUpdateArray = this.outputUpdate();
    mOutputHistoryArray = this.outputHistory();
}
```

**calling the constructor**:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBCR_FULL_FMS_1_SENT = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(SPPService.SPP_SERVICE_INTENT_ACTION_FULL_FMS_1)) {
            mFMSMsg1 = intent.getStringExtra(SPPService.SPP_SERVICE_INTENT_KEY_FULL_FMS_1);
            //Log.i(TAG, SubTag.bullet("mBCR_FMS_MSG_1_SENT", "mFMSMsg1: " + mFMSMsg1));

            DEM dem = new DEM(mFMSMsg1); //<<===this line Error:(563, 75)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the related code

Comment: @Jens please see the update

Comment: And how do you call it?

Comment: @Jens like this  DEM dem = new DEM(mFMSMsg1); where mFMS1 is a string

Comment: and which line is Error:(563, 75)

Comment: Please give us more context, like the whole class

Comment: @Jens i updated the question with more code..please have a look

Comment: @AdamRatzman i updated the question with nore code..please have alook

Comment: Maybe a wrong Import of class DEM?

Comment: @Jens i removed the import and reimported it automatically again but the problem exists

Comment: I'm stumped ;-; is this an external library or did you just copy the code into your project?

Comment: @AdamRatzman DEM is in a jar file imported into Android APP

Comment: And you're using the correct version of that Jar file where the `DEM(String)` constructor exists?

Comment: @Tom yes i am using the correct version. i even re-generated the jar file and re-imported it..and the class in the jar has only one constructor that accepts String parameter